# Extract lines from a string PHP

Tags: php

So I've got a string being added via imap in a PHP script. There's always 12 lines in the email - always. I need to be able to assign each line to a variable.

Usually, I'd use some markers to signify the end/start of the value from the email but that's not an option in this case (they're being sent from ships and so a larger email means more money).

The email looks like -

```
CCL21045
04/03/2020
1800
32.50
17.20
Nil
Nil
```

It's all sent as one block with no white space in between the lines. I need to get the 4 lines above into their own variables.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide an example as to what the "email" looks like? Also, do you have any code you've written so far that we can help with?

Comment: `explode("\n", $string)` will split the string into an array of lines. Then you can access the specific lines you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "a string being added via map"? How does that relate to email? Did you mean IMAP?

Comment: @newfurniturey - have updated post to show the content of the email. no code to share as of yet as unsure how to best achieve it

Comment: @Barmar sorry should have said imap (have updated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the format will **always** be in the same order, you could use PHP's [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/explode) to split the input by lines into individual variables. Something like:

```php
[$report_date, $coordinates, $speed, $destination, ] = explode("\n", $email);
```

Even if it's not in a specific order, you can still use `explode()` to split the input into an array and loop over each line to match it to what you want/need. i.e.:

```php
$lines = explode("\n", $email);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (preg_match('@^\d{2}/\d{2}\d{4}$@', $line)) {
        $report_date = $line;
    }

    // ... more rules for other input types
}
```